# Can I get from which provider came from a GPS position?

Tags: android, location

Is there are a way to find out which providers gives me a concrete location position? Is it come from passive, network or GPS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Location`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html) object that you receive has a [`getProvider()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getProvider%28%29) method which will return who generated that location.

Answer (score 0):

if u have a reference to `Location` object then you can call `getProvider()` method using that reference which will return you the provider that was used to give the location